# Referrer URL for Views - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, redirect, environment-variables, modal-dialog, referrer

I'm trying to grab the referrer URL, and have used a couple different methods.  The one that seemed most reliable, was below:

```
session[:login_refer] = request.url
```

However, it sometimes causes an error by capturing the URL of modals (I'm using twitter bootstrap).  This is a problem is someone clicks a modal, but then clicks login, and is then redirected back...since the link is broken (i.e. can't go to modal directly).

Is there a way to ensure that it only catches actual pages, and not urls for modals / actions?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try `request.referer`    ?

Comment: yeah, seems to not work that great on the iPhone for some reason...